# height should be set to auto to avoid pixelation in the post thumbnail function

Tags: php, functions, css, post-thumbnails

The code in question →

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
```

The generated output in **browser** is like this →

```
<img width="1620" height="973" src="..../site04/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/audi_ileana.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="..../site04/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/audi_ileana.jpg 1620w, http://......./site04/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/audi_ileana-300x180.jpg 300w, ....../site04/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/audi_ileana-768x461.jpg 768w, http://....../site04/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/audi_ileana-1024x615.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1620px) 100vw, 1620px">
```

## Anticipated result →

I want that height should output as "auto" value.

---

**I tried this:**

```
<div class="pimg">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
</div>
```

and its css:

```
.pimg img {max-with:100%; height:auto;}
```

Comment: (mandatory) [What have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter to remove height and width attributes from images, as explained in this [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-width-and-height-attributes-from-inserted-images/). Place the following in your themes `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );

function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to touch the core functions written by Automattic team? Are their any repercussion?

Comment: @TheWPNovice Filters where introduced to do exactly that. The repercussions are that you might break things, this is always a possibility. But in a case like this I'd guess you're fine

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could try using [another](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) function to get just the url then echo that inside img:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Post thumbnail image">
```

And style it completely yourself.

Comment: Yes, yes, but you forget to put that into esc_url → `<img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_the_post_thumbnail_url()); ?>" alt="Post thumbnail image">`